# Java to XML Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

New to Android Development and was wondering if there was some way of taking the users input to create an activity? For example say the user is going through the process of setting up a profile of themself. One of the questions is "how many pets do you have?". The user inputs "4" and then clicks the 'Next' button (which opens the next activity).

How would I take the users input of "4" to create four editText objects in the next activity so that the user can now input the name's of his/her's pets?

I'm an ok-ish programmer (have never touched XML before though) so you don't need to go into much detail I just don't know how I would access this variable to create the four editText objects. From what I've found out you can't add strings to the resources at run-time nor can even edit/append files in resources.

I was thinking of writing an XML file from java and making the activity (written in XML) read the XML file if that's even possible? Can XML files read XML files?

Comment: Try to read the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html first. It is pretty accessible, you just have to read it.

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with xml

the user's input will be stored in a different data type like a string. If you need to load a new activity, one thing you can do is pass information in an android `Bundle` type.

you start new activities with `intent` data types. the `intent` data type has a `putExtra` method, where you can put variables in.

after you `startActivity(yourIntent)` the new activity can call `Bundle` and that has a method called `getExtra` associated with `getIntent()`

these should guide you at least

Comment: Thanks, but I knew all that. Its dynamic layouts I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Intents.

```
String 1 = et.getText().toString();
String 2 = et.getText().toString();
String 3 = et.getText().toString();
String 4 = et.getText().toString();

Intent i = new Intent(this, newclass.class).
i.putExtras("key1", 1);
```

// and so on.

// Then you get the data by.

```
bundle extras = i.getExtras();
string temps1 = extras.getString("key1", null);
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Thanks but I know all that. Looking for dynamic layouts

Comment: I don't know what you mean then, can you explain more? By your scenario you wanted to have four objects from the profile class to the name class and this is how you do it; can you clarify some more?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is not really the creation of activities, but rather the creation of layouts. As you're already aware, Android allows you to define a layout using xml and Activities have a simple method to call to set their content view based on that xml. Layouts are not required to be defined in xml though; they can be programatically created.

When you start an activity you create an `Intent` for it, and you are able to add "extras" to this intent; by doing that you can pass parameters into your activity and it can use those as hints for how to build the layout.

Do some research on programatic layouts (http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2007/12/xml-and-programmatic-layout.html might help) and you will probably figure out what you need to know.

Comment: Great this sounds like what I need to do. I already knew about passing extras with Intent. So I will just create the layout without XML then

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help. If you feel that my post has helped you, please accept it by clicking the check next to it. Thanks, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data (in your case user input) with the help of intent.
You can send data by using putExtra. [Here is good tutorial for you](http://javasrilankansupport.blogspot.in/2012/06/send-data-to-another-activity-simple.html).

For dynamic layout you can inflate your current layout and add controls to your current view. For dynamic layout [this is good tutorial to refer](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/).

I hope this two two tutorial will help you.

Comment: Cheers Dynamic layouts is what I was looking for